# SWIFT - Create/Change NSIndexPath with length equal to 1

Tags: ios, swift, nsindexpath

So right now, the indexPath length is 2. Is there a way that I can change it to 1? Will I have to create a different NSIndexPath manually with the length 1? If so, how would I go about doing it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a new `NSIndexPath`. If you need to remove a specific value you must play with pointers in Swift

```
let originalPath = NSIndexPath(indexes: [1,2,3], length: 3)
var indexes = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.alloc(originalPath.length)
originalPath.getIndexes(indexes) // This extracts values from NSIndexPath

var newValues = Array<Int>()
// Iterate over the pointer array
for val in UnsafeBufferPointer(start: indexes, count: originalPath.length) {
    // Determine values which you want in the new NSIndexPath
    newValues.append(val)
}

let newPath = NSIndexPath(indexes: newValues, length: newValues.count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really described what and why you're trying to do, but

```
myIndexPath = myIndexPath.indexPathByRemovingLastIndex()
```